# casting error using the numbapro cuda extension

Tags: python, anaconda, numba, numba-pro

I'm trying to run a little device kernel function on a shared array:

```
from numbapro import cuda, float32

@cuda.jit('void(float32[:,:],float32,float32)',device=True)
def cu_calculate_distance(template, dx, dy) : 
    side_length = template.shape[0]
    cen = side_length/2
    for i in xrange(side_length) : 
        for j in xrange(side_length) : 
            template[i,j] = math.sqrt(((i-cen)*dx)**2 + ((j-cen)*dy)**2)

@cuda.autojit
def cuda_test() :
    t = cuda.shared.array(shape=(100,100),dtype=float32)
    dx = float32(1/100.)
    cu_calculate_distance(t,dx,dx)
```

When I try to run the cuda_test() function, I get the error:

```
CompilerError: At line 523:
During: instruction codegen
TypeError: array(float32, 2, C) does not support casting when trying to cast to array(float32, 2, A)
```

I don't understand this cast error -- as far as I can tell, I'm not actually recasting the array anywhere -- it's declared as a float32 shared array and it's being passed to a function that takes a float32 array. What am I missing?